# Python unittest multiple tests on tcp server with single socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, python-unittest

I am trying to test my implementation of a simple service that uses a TCP socket. I would like to test my server without creating a connection for every test case. I would like to make a single connection for the entire test suite. Currently I have something that looks like this..

```
class Test_service(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1(self):
        client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        client_socket.connect(('', port_number))
        client_socket.send('message1'.encode())
        self.assertEqual(client_socket.recv(1024).decode(), 'reply1')
        client_socket.close()

    def test_2(self):
        client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        client_socket.connect(('', port_number))
        client_socket.send('message2'.encode())
        self.assertEqual(client_socket.recv(1024).decode(), 'reply2')
        client_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

What is a good way to keep a single socket connection open and have multiple test cases use that connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-tests) you'll find that can put `setUp` and `tearDown` methods in your test class that will get executed once. So you can do something like:

```
class Test_service(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        client_socket.connect(('', port_number))

    def tearDown(self):
        client_socket.close()

    def test_1(self):
        client_socket.send('message1'.encode())
        self.assertEqual(client_socket.recv(1024).decode(), 'reply1')

    def test_2(self):
        client_socket.send('message2'.encode())
        self.assertEqual(client_socket.recv(1024).decode(), 'reply2')
```